# Postgresql referential integrity constraints in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, database-design, activerecord

Came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3438822/367985) post & it says *referential integrity handled by the DB is not the Rails way at all.*

But consider this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
end

class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

#User Model
id: integer, name: string,department_id: integer
#Department Model
id: integer, name: string
```

Here I need to create a new user & enforce following rules

- User should be assigned to a department
- the `users.department_id` should match `departments.id`
- if `users.department_id` doesn't not match with `departments.id`, the record should NOT be created & raise an error.

Now, how to I accomplish this in rails way? Or Adding foreign key by  dropping raw SQL in a migration is only way to go?

Comment: The "Rails way" is simpleminded, foolish, and subject to race conditions (among other things). If you care at all about your data, you will use real FKs in the database, [foreigner](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner) will help you with this until the Rails devs tone down the attitude in favor of good sense.

Comment: Yes, it seems weird but hey, rails is an opinionated software :)

Comment: But their logic has gaping holes in it and they let their attitude get in the way of solid software. At least they admit the shortcomings of their approach wrt uniqueness in the [Validations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#why-use-validations). I've seen enough *impossible* things happen to know better and I'm at least as opinionated as Rails :)

Comment: After reading the DHH quote I never would have guessed he was talking about referential integrity (is he?) but instead about stuff like the database not saving an order, because the total order value is below a minimum threshold or something like that. Anyway, @muistooshort is right of course :)

Comment: @DanielRikowski: A foreign key *is* a constraint and is how databases enforce referential integrity; by default, Rails doesn't know what a real FK is so I think DHH was talking about referential integrity (or maybe he just doesn't understand relational databases well enough to know about FKs). Data integrity is the database's job, that's why you use one instead of a pile of flat files. I load my databases with FKs and CHECKs and triggers and all that good stuff: fixing bugs in code is easy, bugs in your database are often permanent. IMO of course but my opinion is right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails, you just add this to your User model:

```
validates_presence_of :department
```

Rails will check for a valid department before allowing a save operation. You can also use a gem like foreigner to add foreign keys to your tables as well if you desire. I usually do this because I inevitably find myself needing to bulk load data directly at some point.

Comment: I already had this validation but i was validating `department_id` . changing it to `department` & it works now. But I wonder why it works now & didn't work earlier?

Comment: If you are validation the presence of an ID, you make sure that the ID field is filled, but not if the ID actually references an existing row. By validating the association you make sure that there is a matching row referenced by that ID.

Answer (score 1):

If Lukas' answer doesn't suite your needs you could also use before/after save hooks on the model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :validate_department

  def validate_department
     #validate the department
     #raise an error if invalid?
  end

end
```